# jQuery update in MVC3 Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010. When i create a new MVC3 project there is a folder called Script that create automatically with some jQuery 1.5.1 version that is not latest jQuery How should i update them, that when i will create a new MVC3 project that will gather jQuery new version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update jQuery and download/update a lot of other useful packages with NuGet. You can find UI for it under **Tools\Library Package Manager** or use a PowerShell console (Package Manager Console). Here is [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You could update the jQuery NuGet package which is already installed when you create a new project. This will bring you the latest version of the package. Or you could manually download the latest jQuery version and reference it in your project. Or you could use a CDN such as Google's.

If you want to have the latest version referenced everytime you create a new project you will have to write a custom project template.

Comment: Thank u so much your answer is so good it help me to know lot of thing... :)